# Entity Framework and dependency injection

Tags: entity-framework, unity-container

I'm using Entity Framework and the Unity as IoC. I want to use constructor injection within entities with ability to configure them from both config and run-time. I don't want to use the injection via properties. I want to make it the way so I don't need and any handlers in object context that supports injection for my entities. This sample I consider as the last resort  [Sample](http://rogeralsing.com/2009/05/30/entity-framework-4-entity-dependency-injection/) but I hope there are other ways to implement this. There may be some extensions to the Unity or other IoC so that ObjectContext could resolve dependencies on its own.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think your answer is clear enough. You should write more details to get answer.

Answer (score 0):

use [Dependency] attribute for you constructor

see Unity 2 documentation in codeplex or msdn